# How can I quickly collect the chaos emeralds in the Security Hall?

Tags: sonic-adventure-2-battle

I'm in the Security Hall level (Stage 8 in the dark storyline) of Sonic Adventure 2, and I'm struggling to collect the 3 chaos emeralds within the 5-minute time limit, mainly because, every time I die/run out of time, the emeralds change location. Also, sometimes the emeralds seem to be in stupid places, that I never would have guessed.

On this particular level, is there an easy way to quickly collect all 3 chaos emeralds within 5 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a bit of a thoughts dump but please bear with me.

First off don't focus blindly on the current target it's quite possible to stumble across one that you aren't currently tracking.

Initially i would recommend taking a quick look around the large fans, it's fairly likely one of the emeralds is either floating above one of them or inside a nearby crate.

Don't run past enemies that get in your path, almost any of them could be carrying an emerald.

If you get among the safes start at the highest possible row the emerald could be in and work your way down as ascending is a pain.

Don't waste too much time searching the highest room if you quickly run around near where you came in and don't get a signal you're almost certainly in the wrong place.
Talking more about the upper area, if you know an emerald is in the laser filled section look and see where it is before going in, not knowing exactly where to go is likely to get you killed or knocked around for far too long.